# Swift - Trailing Closure Syntax

Tags: callback, arguments, swift

I'm diving into Swift lang by Apple and have some problems using the trailing closure syntax, example:

```
func test(txt: String, resolve: (name: String) -> Void) {
   resolve(name: "Dodo")
}

// Errors here complaining on resolve param
test("hello", (name: String) {
   println("callback")
})
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you have the wrong closure syntax

```
test("hello", {(name: String) in 
    println("callback")
})
```

or

```
test("hello", {
   println("callback: \($0)")
})
```

or

```
test("hello") {(name: String) in 
    println("callback")
}
```

or

```
test("hello") {
   println("callback: \($0)")
}
```

Comment: I have one more question, this ``resolve(name: name)`` throws an error  ``use of unresolved identifier 'name'``.. how to pass arguments in callback call?

Comment: hi i dont get that. can you share the code that fails?

Comment: I have a question... In the first code example that you provided above, you have "{(name: String) in".  What's the semantic meaning of "in" when used in this context?

Comment: In is the separator between parameters and statements