# Swift callbacks syntax issue

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to **Swift**, and I'm trying to declare a function that receives a callback.

```
func getAll(callback: (students: [Student]!) -> Void) {
    // http request to get a list of students and parse it

    callback(students: students)
}
```

And when calling the function, I'm doing:

```
obj.getAll() {
    (students: [Student]!) in

    // Callback code
}
```

But it won't build, it says: `Cannot invoke getAll with an argument list of type '(([Student]!) -> _)'`

I was following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249202/swift-anonymus-function-with-arguments-as-callback-syntax) as a guide, what did I miss?

Comment: Just as a side note. You should be able to omit `-> Void`. Swift implicitly adds that.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Student {

}

func getAll(callback: (students: [Student]!) -> Void) {
    // http request to get a list of students and parse it
    let students = [Student]()

    callback(students: students)
}

getAll { (students) -> Void in
    println(students)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not send an argument students, but receive a parameter, that is why you implement it like this:

```
obj.getAll { (students) -> Void in
    // Callback code
}
```

If you are not sure about the closures, always use autocomplete and you won't have to worry about the syntax. Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this different to the one he has? Isn't it the same?

Comment: It is not different. But I explained the difference between the arguments and students. I guess I should elaborate a bit more my answer so it teaches more about the Swift closures. Just giving someone code without an explaination won't help someone become a better developer.

Comment: While I agree there is no need to have the declaration there, at the same time it is not a mistake. I doubt he is getting the error because of the declaration (as it is completely valid: students should be of type [Student]!). Or am I confused here? Btw, I am not quite sure I understand the reasoning either. You do send the function as an argument, so the type can be declared.

Answer (score 0):

Remove type declaration in your call

```
obj.getAll() {
    students in
    // Callback code
}
```